# Apache URL rewriting - matching directory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a *.htaccess* file with the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^api\/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\/?([0-9=a-zA-Z%]+)?\/?$   api.php?service=$1&param=$2 [QSA,L]
```

For some reason, it's working on my host, but not on my local LAMP-installation. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

*Apache version:* Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)

*Error message:* 404 Not Found ("The requested URL /api/word/search/ was not found on this server.")

**Edit**: There is another rewrite rule that is working, so the mod_rewrite module is activated:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\.page$    index.php?template=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Apache site configuration is (locally):

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/Development-Env
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/Development-Env/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

**Edit #2** I am trying to match `http://localhost/api/service/method/`.

Comment: can you please show me the url that you are tryiing 
api/dir1/dir2/someging ?

Comment: @ddjikic I've updated my original post.

Comment: Try adding this on top of the rewrite rule-set `Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews`

Comment: @faa That solved it! Post it, and I'll mark this question as answered! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews` in your question, I guess the problem is MultiViews is enabled.

You may try adding this line on top of the rewrite rule-set:

`Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews`

Answer (score 1):

it is possible that apache mod rewrite is not enabled , or htaccess not alowed.
and dont forget before all of that

```
RewriteEngine On
```

you cna also
try `RewriteRule ^api/(.*)/(.*)$ api.php?a=$1&d=$2 [NC]`

man use codeigniter if you need an api you have a api i used this

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/

Comment: Thank you for your response. `mod_rewrite` is enabled.